# crm dynamics 2016 limit the number of files in a note

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to attach a document to the opportunity. My question is
Can the note be altered so that only one file can be attached and not several?

some example?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more details as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett the one that knows of crm dynamics perfectly understands the question

Comment: There’s no system settings/config available as OOB to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin on Pre-operation stage of Annotation Create message to evaluate if there is an attachment already for that particular Opportunity & stop the execution by throwing `InvalidPluginExecutionException` exception.

You can attach only one file in each Notes entry. So this should work.

Comment: Hello arun, thanks for replying. The truth is a bit half-hearted, I've already learned to consume the CRM api and at this precise moment I'm trying to limit the notes but I can not find the correct field.
Do you happen to have an example to base yourself on?
It would be very helpful, Thank you very much

Comment: @CamiloLópez you know that's too broad in SO. Add your code attempt in question, we can solve if any particular problem exists..